# Given array [1, 5, 6, -11, 6, 2] return pairs when added together to equal X

Tags: python

Hey guys im currently in lambda school and im in labs at the moment. I had a mock interview and during the final 20 minutes i was given a coding challenge. The question above was the question i was asked. The way i went about solving this was creating 2 loops like this

```
my_function(x):
    new_array = []

    for i in array:
        for j in array:
            if i + j == X:
                new_array.append([i, j])
    return new_array
```

This was returning the pairs that added up to equal a given X. But the person interviewing me said the way i went about solving the problem was incorrect. Could someone please explain a more efficient way to solve this?

Comment: Search for two sum

Comment: google prefix sums or the two-sum problem on leetcode.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `new_array` variable contains all the pairs from the array. You haven't written the condition for X+Y=C. You can try this way:

```
new_array = []
for i in range(len(array)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(array)):
        if array[i]+array[j]==x:
            new_array.append([i,j])
```

Edit: This solution takes O(n^2) time and O(1) space. You can optimize this by using an extra space which is a Hash table:

```
out = {}
for i, num in enumerate(array):
    n = x - num
    if n not in out:
        h[num] = i
    else:
        new_array.append([h[n], i])
```

This gives O(n) time and O(n) space complexity.
**Explanation of above code**:
Iterate through the array and check if element exist in the hash table. If exist, append it to the output, else enter the value into the hash table

Comment: Youre so right sorry i had the interview a couple days ago i forgot some code. I did include that logic though in my original solution.

Comment: I have edited the answer with another optimized solution. Please consider accepting the answer  if you find the solution helpful

Answer (score 1):

Looping through the array is a correct way to solve this problem but you have a condition, you only return the pairs that satisfy that condition: You only return the pair [i,j] if it is equal to x.

So here is a working way to do it is :

```
def my_function(array, x):
    new_array = []

    for i in array:
        for j in array:
            if((i+j)==x):
                new_array.append([i, j])
    return new_array
```

This will give you all possible combinations that result when added in the number x, even combinations of the same number for example :

```
x = 10
array = [5,2,3,8]
new_array = [[5,5], [2,8], [8,2]]
```

To avoid testing the same number (in our example 5) and it happens when i=j, and taking it as a combination here is an easy way to do it :

```
def my_function(array, x):
    new_array = []
    for i in range(len(array)):
        for j in range(len(array)):
            if (((array[i]+array[j])==x)and(i!=j)):
                new_array.append([array[i],array[j])
```

This will give you :

```
x = 10
array = [5,2,3,8]
new_array = [[2,8], [8,2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

> This was returning the pairs that added up to equal a given X.

You have some list of values like:

```
[1, 5, 6, -11, 6, 2]
```

You're looking for two elements `x` and `y` that satisfy `x + y = C`. Framing this another way: given some element `x`, you're looking to check whether `y = C - x` is in the list.

Comment: It's not quite that simple, as if `C = 10` and `x = 5` then `y = 5` is also in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Given an array when I found number equal to "num" then returns the pair.

Code:

```
def find_sum(num):
 array_1 = [1, 5, 6, -11, 6, 2]
 array_2 = [1, 5, 6, -11, 6, 2]

 for i in array_1:
   for j in array_2:
     if (i + j) == num:
       return (i,j)

print (find_sum(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

As a bonus, you can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) with [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to solve this:

```
from itertools import combinations

a = [1, 5, 6, -11, 6, 2]
x = 7
[t for t in combinations(a,2) if sum(t) == x]
```

**Output**

```
[(1, 6), (1, 6), (5, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

with the few informations that you gave us about the problem, this is my solution
**NOTE:** *This is probably not the optimal way and I wasn't sure if you could use the same number to create a pair. I'm also not a professional and this is only to show one of the multiple ways to do it*

```
def function(array, x):
res = [x - el for el in array]
pairs = []
for el in res:
    try:
        pair = (x - el, array[array.index(el)])
        pairs.append(pair)
    except:
        pass
return list(set(pairs))
```

1. You create a function that takes an **array** with an **x** value to match.
2. In that function, you add a variable named 'res' that **substracts** **'x'** with **every values** from the array.
3. You also add a variable that will contains the **pairs**.
4. You now loop for every elements **(el)** in the result **(res).**
5. **(You need a try/catch for that).**
6. You create a tuple named **'pair'** that contains the value of **'x - (the current value in your loop)'** AND the value of your array at the index of **array.index(element).**
   https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-index/
7. Add that pair to the pair list **(pairs)**.
8. return a **set** that will remove the duplicates from your pairs.

You should obtain a result like this:

```
# CASE 1
array = [1, 5, 6, -11, 6, 2]
x = 6
print(function(array, x))
# Result: [(1, 5), (5, 1)]

# CASE 2
array = [1, 5, 6, -11, 6, 2]
x = 10
print(function(array, x))
# Result: [(5, 5)]

# CASE 3
array = [1, 5, 6, -11, 6, 2]
x = 1
print(function(array, x))
# Result: []
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sumpairs(l, s):
    i = 0
    final_list=[]
    while i < len(l):
       val = s - l[i]
       if val in l:
         final_list.append((val,l[i]))
       i += 1
return final_list

print(sumpairs(l, s))

'''
Input:
l = [1, 5, 6, -11, 6, 2]
s = 6
output:
[(5, 1), (1, 5)]
'''
```